# What is causing node.js to crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Unfamiliar with javascript/node.js, and I'm unable to get my script to run:

```
import { IDS, MangoGroup, MangoClient } from '@blockworks-foundation/mango-client';
import { Account, Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Market } from '@project-serum/serum';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

setInterval(function () {
    console.log("timer that keeps nodejs processing running");
}, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

As you can see, this script is essentially blank. The imports alone are causing it to fail. If I remove the imports, then node.js stays running.

What's the problem?

EDIT: Here is the output: [gist](https://gist.github.com/bureto/e81159e95274163c65f17eeeae6e917b)

Comment: What error is shown when node crashes?

Comment: What import does crash it ? And what the error message ?

Comment: I tried each import individually and it doesn't seem to matter which module, they all cause it to fail. Is my syntax wrong or something?

Comment: How are you launching node.exe?  How do you know it crashed?

Comment: Okay so I guess visual studio (or my setup of it) just is really bad at debugging. I ran the script using terminal (not visual studio) and it finally gave me the error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: No sense to write as answer. There just need to use "require" instead of "require". Also explore how to require them in right way, appropriately from their official package-pages

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the script using nodejs, add **"type": "module"** in the package.json file. I hope this will solve your issue.